# Identifying recurring transaction clusters (subscriptions) at a user level

Tags: clustering, machine-learning-model, k-means, semi-supervised-learning

I need some help converting this issue into a machine learning problem.

#### Goal:

Grouping credit charges into clusters of recurring transactions per user

#### Input data:

- List of credit card charges with

  - `tx_id`, `username`, `amount`, `date`, `transaction_name`,`merchant_id`
  - also manually labeled data of `cluster_id`s that group certain transactions together that can be used for supervised learning

#### Example

| tx_id | username | amount | date | transaction_name | merchant_id | cluster_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tx_1 | user123 | 9.99 | 8/1/23 | Amazon Coffee Sub | amazon | user123_999 |
| tx_2 | user123 | 27.99 | 8/10/23 | Amazon Dog Food Sub | amazon | user123_2799 |
| tx_3 | user123 | 9.99 | 9/1/23 | Amazon Coffee Sub | amazon | user123_999 |
| tx_4 | user123 | 27.99 | 9/10/23 | Amazon Dog Food Sub | amazon | user123_2799 |
| tx_5 | user123 | 35.55 | 9/15/23 | Amazon One Off purchase | amazon | null |
| tx_6 | user567 | 12.99 | 8/2/23 | Amazon Tea Sub | amazon | user567_999 |
| tx_7 | user567 | 25.99 | 8/16/23 | Amazon Cat Food Sub | amazon | user567_2799 |
| tx_8 | user567 | 12.99 | 9/2/23 | Amazon Tea Sub | amazon | user567_999 |
| tx_9 | user567 | 25.99 | 9/16/23 | Amazon Cat Food Sub | amazon | user567_2799 |
| tx_10 | user567 | 45.55 | 9/21/23 | Amazon One Off purchase | amazon | null |

#### Ideal Output:

Some way of saying that the following transactions should be "clustered"

- tx_1, tx_3
- tx_2, tx_4
- tx6, tx_8
- tx_7, tx_9

#### Questions / thoughts

- I've looked into k-means and other clustering models but wasn't sure if it's the right approach

  - The `k` number can be different per user per merchant
  - Some username, merchant combinations may be be super clean (same amount happening exactly 1 month apart) and all belong to one cluster
  - Each "cluster" should always have one only unique username, merchant. In other words, I don't want to group all amazon coffee subscriptions for all users into one cluster. I want a different cluster per user
  - I do have labeled data that can be used for supervised learning
- Supervised classification algorithms

  - Same issue with k-means, user123 and user567 shouldn't have any cluster overlaps
  - There are no pre-defined "cluster_ids" (or lables) found in the training set that would appear in the output of the test set

Put in a different way, I want to build a model that can learn specific characteristics of what a recurring "cluster" should look like such as

- amount similarity
- charge date similarity (eg. always happening on the 1st of the month)

and share the learnings across different users. Once I have the model and pass in two transactions that are exactly a month apart with similar amounts for the same username/merchant, I would like the model to tell me that those two transactions should be considered a "cluster".